# wget page and related assets to a specified local folder strucure

Tags: shell, web-scraping, wget

I would like to use wget to download a single page with all of its related css, images, js, and fonts into this folder structure:

```
site/
  --one .html file
  client_files/
    css/
      --all style sheets
    img/
      --all image assets
    js/
      --all js files
    fonts/
      --all fonts files
```

I have been using httrack in the past to scrape a clients page, but have always needed to manually sort out all of the client files and paths. Is this possible with wget?

..So far I have the follwing to get a single page but am not sure about setting this type of specific folder structure:

```
wget --mirror --page-requisites --adjust-extension --no-parent --convert-links --directory-prefix=sousers --cut-dirs=4 --level=1 http://www.website.com/index.php/Other/a-page
```

Any help would be much appreciated.